# How to show the error message for an empty array on the first input field that uses useField?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a bunch of input fields in my form, like this:

```
<TouchedFeedbackSelect
    label="Language"
    name='languages[0]'
    options={...}
/>

<TouchedFeedbackSelect
    label="Language"
    name='languages[1]'
    options={...}
/>

<TouchedFeedbackSelect
    label="Language"
    name='languages[2]'
    options={...}
/>
```

Internally, they use Formik's `` hook to handle the error state:

```
const TouchedFeedbackSelect = ({ label, options, helpText, ...props }: TouchedFeedbackSelectProps & FieldHookConfig<string>) => {
    const [field, meta] = (props);

    return (
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId={props.name}>
            <Form.Label id={props.name + "-select-label"}>{label}</Form.Label>
            <Form.Select
                {...field}
                isInvalid={meta.touched && !!meta.error}
                aria-describedby={`${props.name}-feedback" ${props.name}-help`}
                aria-labelledby={props.name + "-select-label"}
            >
                {options}
            </Form.Select>
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid" id={props.name + "-feedback"}>{meta.error}</Form.Control.Feedback>
            <Form.Text id={props.name + "-help"} muted>
                {helpText}
            </Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>
    );
}

export default TouchedFeedbackSelect;
```

The **validation schema requires the array to have one element**, meaning that only **one** select field has to contain a value:

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    [...]
    languages: Yup.array(Yup.string())
        .min(1, 'Required'),
    [...]
});
```

Question: **How can I let the first input field show the error message when the array is empty**? Since I pass `languages[0]` and not `language` as the name to the first input field, `` is not connected to the `validationSchema`.

If my approach is wrong, what's the correct way to show the error message here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by separating the language input fields into separate required (`language`) and optional (`additionalLanguages`) fields.

```
// Required field
<TouchedFeedbackSelect
    label="Language"
    name="language"
    options={...}
    helpText="What's the language of the resource?"
/>
// Optional fields
<FieldArray name='additionalLanguages'>
    {arrayHelpers => (
        <div>
            {formik.values.additionalLanguages.length > 0 &&
                formik.values.additionalLanguages.map((additionalLanguage, index) => (
                    <TouchedFeedbackSelect
                        label={...}
                        name={'additionalLanguages[' + index + ']'}
                        key={'additionalLanguage-' + (index + 1)}
                        options={...}
                        helpText="What other language is this resource available in?"
                    />
                ))
            }
            {formik.values.additionalLanguages.length < 9 &&
                <Button
                    onClick={() => arrayHelpers.push('')}>
                    + Add another language
                </Button>
            }
            {formik.values.additionalLanguages.length > 0 &&
                <Button
                    onClick={() => arrayHelpers.remove(formik.values.additionalLanguages.length - 1)}>
                    - Remove language
                </Button>
            }
        </div>
    )}
</>
```

**Note:** `FieldArray` is a Formik component to make working with arrays in forms easier.

**Note 2:** For some reason, `arrayHelpers.pop()` always removed two fields at once, so I use `remove` with the last index instead.

**However, I still wanted to accept the input if the `language` field is empty, but an `additionalLanguage` is selected**, so I changed Yup's validation schema the following way:

```
language: Yup.string()
    .when('additionalLanguages', {
        is: (additionalLanguages: string[]) => additionalLanguages.filter(language => language).length < 1,
        then: Yup.string().required("Required")
    }),
```

I also send everything as a single array to my server:

```
languages: [values.language, ...values.additionalLanguages],
```